# Size of Selected Records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, storage

Anyone know how to find the space that a group of records from a single table are using?  We know how to find the size of the table and estimate the size given the data types, but we'd like to know the exact size on disk.  Looking for something like

select size(t.*) from sometable t

or something from sys views.

Comment: The size will vary per row if you use `NVARCHAR`/`VARCHAR`, and whether or not you're using compression. There's also the question of whether you want to include indexes in the count. The actual, concrete length of a particular column in a particular row can be determined with the `DATALENGTH` function (and then you can sum over that), but it's not clear that gives you what you want. Note that simply adding the length of all rows is not necessarily the size of the row, and adding sizes of rows doesn't give you the number of pages actually used.

Comment: In short, what I'm really asking is "what do you consider the exact size on disk, and why is it more useful to you than the average size of a row given by `tablesize / row count`"?

Comment: Thanks Jeroen.  Basically, if we delete all of the records, how much space will we save.

Comment: Well, if you delete *all* of the records, you will free up exactly as much space as is taken up by the entire table -- you can determine how much this is by calling `sp_spaceused '[sometable]'`. Note that simply deleting data will not make the data file any smaller, but simply make the room available for future data. (Making it smaller involves shrinking, but you don't want to do that if you can help it, since it leads to fragmentation.)

Comment: meant deleting all of the records selected.  I'll just use the table size / row count to average the size of each record.  Thanks.